# Datomic get year from instant

Tags: datomic

I have an attribute of type instant and I want to query for the year.

```
[:find ?year
 :where
 [?t :x/date ?date]
 [((fn [dt] (+ (.getYear dt) 1900)) ?date) ?year]]
```

Is there a better way to do this query?

Comment: Sorry, I don't see the point, are you concerned about performance?